# Can't understand how a long double number can be greater than 2^80

Tags: c, math, taylor-series

So i was solving the Taylor series , which is here:

[image: The Taylor series]

This is the code :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include<conio.h>  
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<math.h>  
long double Fact(long double h) { 
if (h <= 0) return 1; 
else return h*Fact(h - 1); 
 } 

void main(void) { 
int p = 0; 
long double s = 0, k = 0, c = 0, l = 0,d=0; 
int n = 0, x = 0; 
printf(" n "); 
scanf("%d", &n);  
printf(" x "); 
scanf("%d", &x); 
d = x; 
while (n>=0) { 
  k = pow(-1, n); 
  c = (2 * n + 1); 
  l = Fact(c); 
  d = pow(x, 2 * n + 1);  
  s = s+ ((k / l)*d); 
  n = n - 1; 
   } 
printf("Result : %.16LG\n", s); 
_getch(); 
 }
```

The question is : how could a long double be grater than 2^80 value if I enter `n = 16` and `x = 2,147,483,646`  but it still writes correct result (i compared the result of the programm with wolfram alfa)

Comment: Why do you find it strange? This is prefectly natural for a floating-point representation.

Comment: Look up the specs for a long double. Perhaps you're thinking it's an integer type. It's not an integer type, but a floating point type. So it has an exponent and mantissa in memory. The supported exponent is > 80.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ first; don't use Russian in your source code here. identifiers and `printf` format control strings should be understandable in English. Next time, provide some [MCVE]; this question will be closed since off-topic

Comment: @AnT,2 147 483 646 ^ 16 is bigger , than long double can accomadate , so how is it possible to get right result despite of this

Comment: How did you write "2^80" without using 80 characters?  `long double` does the same thing.  It uses _exponential notation_ in its encoding.

Comment: @Elvin: I can create type that occupies only one bit of memory. Value `0` in that bit would stand for `0`, while value `1` would stand for `1234567890`. And viola: I just found a way to represent number `1234567890` with just *one* bit of memory! Magic, right? But the price of that "magic" is that with my 1-bit type I cannot represent any other numbers besides `0` and `1234567890`. That's actually exactly how it works with floating-point types. It is more complicated, but the general principle is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's imagine that I decided to invent my own data type, which I'd call `bloat` (like `float`, geddit?). This type would be just one byte wide (8 bits) and use the following representation: bit #0 (the least-significant one) has weight 4<sup>0</sup> = 1, bit #1 has weight 4<sup>1</sup> = 4, bit #2 has weight 4<sup>2</sup> = 16, bit #3 has weight 4<sup>3</sup> = 64 and so on and so forth.

The combination of bits `00010001` in `bloat` would stand for `1 + 256 = 257`. The maximum value representable in `bloat` would be `11111111`, which is `21845`. So, here you are: using my freshly invented `bloat` type I managed to represent value `21845` in just 8 bits of memory. `21845` is greater than 2<sup>14</sup>, yet I somehow managed to squeeze it into just 8 bits! How did I achieve that?

Easy: in order to "stretch" the apparent range of my type I sacrificed some intermediate values. My `bloat` type cannot represent number `2`, for one example. It can't represent number `66`. And so on. There are lots of values under `21845` that my `bloat` cannot represent. If you count all possible different values my `bloat` *can* represent, you will discover that there are exactly `256` of them, i.e exactly 2<sup>8</sup> different values are representable.

Floating-point types, like your `long double` employ pretty much the same principle to "stretch" their range. Their internal format and properties are more complicated than those of my `bloat`, but the underlying idea is the same: the absolute range of a 80-bit floating-point type is much much greater than 2<sup>80</sup> because it "skips" (cannot represent) lots and lots of values inside that range.

The exact details of their internal representation are [widely available on the Net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Comment: simply the best explanation. This is where the ability to reduce to a very simple and easy to understand analogy really shows off its power.

Comment: how did you get 4^n , why 4 ? Is that quaternary number system ?

Comment: This quaternary number system allows us to increase the range of numbers ?Despite of this , it does't allow to present little numbers ?

Comment: @Elvin: It is not quaternary number system (not the traditional one at leat). In quaternary number system you can use digits `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` in each position. In my example you can only have `0` or `1` in each position. Which is why my system has "holes" in its range. As for why I used `4` - it is a random choice. You can use `3`, `5`, `10` or any other "base" greater than `2`. The greater the base - the larger absolute range you'll get (and the larget the "holes" in this range will be).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are talking about 2^80 because you assume that floating point number of size 80 bits can store numbers only up  to 2<sup>80</sup>. Your understanding of floating point numbers is wrong. Unlike unsigned integer number where number is encoded as a binary number, encoding for floating point number is different.

You can learn more on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) but basic idea is that floating point number is encoded as

```
sign * something * 2^something_else
```

Important part here is  `2^something_else`. For 32 FP number `something_else` (exponent) is 8 bits long , that because some special cases means that for normal numbers it can go `−126` to `+127`, for long double assuming it is 80 bit x86 FP it can go to [16383](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format):

Comment: tnx for correction. I am not confused, just eng is not my first language so when I edited my sentence before posting i messed up.

Comment: don't clearly understand you, I know about mantissa and machine order but The float number consists of a sighn (the first bit of first byte ) , machine order (for other bits of the first byte ) and mantissa other bytes . So where exactly long double is there ?

Comment: @bolov I know, but did not want to confuse the readers. I will change it to unsigned so it is technically correct while I avoid going into explaining the signed encoding.

Comment: Elvin - long double is "same" as 32 bit floating point number, it just has more bits, that give it more precission and bigger range. But the mechanism it uses for encoding is the same. You can see more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_Extended_Precision_Format

Answer (score 1):

The x86 extended precision format (if this is what leads you to refer to 80 bits) has 63 mantissa bits and 15 exponent bits (with a 16383 bias, and the value 32767 is reserved).

Hence the largest value it can represent is veryclose to 2 x 2^(32766-16383) ~ 1.189731 x 10^4932, much, much, much larger than 2^80.

The largest representable number with ordinary IEEE double precision is about  1.79769 x 10^308.